# Unexpected difference in iostream behavior between visual studio 2010 and gcc/g++ 4.6.3

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, gcc, iostream

Consider the following code snippet:

```
ofstream o("myFile.txt");

o.precision(14);
o.width(20);
o.setf(ios::showpoint);
o.setf(ios::internal);
o.fill(' ');

double zero = 0.0;

o << zero;
```

The results are:

0.00000000000000 //Visual studio 2010

0.0000000000000  //g++

Is this difference acceptable, or is it a bug in one of the compilers?

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for [`precision`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/precision/) reads (emphasis mine):

> The floating-point precision determines the maximum number of digits
> to be written on insertion operations to express floating-point
> values. How this is interpreted depends on whether the floatfield
> format flag is set to a specific notation (either fixed or scientific)
> or it is unset (using the default notation, which is not necessarily
> equivalent to either fixed nor scientific).
>
> For the default locale:
>
> - Using the default floating-point notation, the precision field specifies the **maximum number of meaningful digits** to display in
>   total **counting both those before and those after the decimal
>   point**. Notice that it is not a minimum, and therefore it does not
>   pad the displayed number with trailing zeros if the number can be
>   displayed with less digits than the precision.
> - In both the fixed and scientific notations, the precision field specifies exactly how many digits to display **after the decimal
>   point**, even if this includes trailing decimal zeros. The digits
>   before the decimal point are not relevant for the precision in this
>   case.

It sounds like the compilers use different [format flags](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/fmtflags/).

Comment: Non-zero values are consistent, so I don't think that's the issue.